# Load local JavaScript file in browser in desktop application

Tags: javascript, winforms, cefsharp

I would like to load local HTML file into CEF browser control in C# WinForm app.

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;

// Initialize cef with the provided settings
Cef.Initialize(settings);            

// Create a browser component
chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser($"file:///{dir}/HTMLPage1.html");

// Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

The HTML is linked to a JavaScript library. It is working if I am using internet URL:

```
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

However it is failed with local script which is manually downloaded:

```
<script src="/Scripts/Plotly/plotly.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea please?

Comment: "_…it is failed…_" throws which error?

Comment: the html is inside the app which i dont know how to find the errors. just nothing shown.

Comment: @beewest, Could you please post here the console output.

Comment: working with <script src="Scripts/Plotly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script> or <script src="./Scripts/Plotly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

Comment: Use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_RegisterResourceHandler.htm